# How to send different message on same group for different users in django channels

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels, django-channels-presence

I am trying to build a real-time ticket reservation app so I want to display the real time seat booking status to users.

For example; I have `user1` and `user2` connected to a group `reservation-1`

Now when the `user1` selects the ticket in group `reservation-1` the seat status will be converted to selected and the message should be broadcasted to all the users connected to the same group with the status of unavailable for that particular seat. But for user1 it should be the status of selected.

My code implementation for JavaScript:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://${window.location.host}/ws/reservation-1');

const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.seats');

seats.forEach(seat => {
    seat.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(seat.dataset.isSelected) {
        // This is an event when user select the seat
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({
          "event": "SELECT",
          "seat": "seat_id" 
        }));
      }else {
        // This is an event when user deselect the seat
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({
          "event": "DESELECT",
          "seat": "seat_id" 
        }));
      }
    }
});

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        // code logic to update the seat based on return values of seat status.
   }
```

My Django server-side consumer code using django-channels:

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class ReservationConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.chat_group_name = 'reservation-1'

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.reservation_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()


    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.reservation_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        user = self.scope['user']
        event = data['event']
        seat_id = data['seat_id']
        
        if event == 'SELECT':
            # this code saves the seat status as selected in database
            save_seat_status_to_selected(user, seat_id)

        if event == 'DESELECT':
            # this code saves the seat status as selected in database
            remove_the_seat_status_of_selected(user, seat_id)

        # this code is now sending a group message to all the users connected to the group.
        # I now want to differentiate the message based on the user who selected the seat 
        # to pass only selected status to the event emitter and the rest of the user with the reserved
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.reservation_group_name,
            {
               # get_reserved_seat will get all the seat status that are in reserved state and also the seat selected by other users
               'reserved': get_reserved_seat(),
               # get_selected_seat will get the seat selected by the user
               'selected': get_selected_seat(user)
            }
        )
```

I am using channel_redis for group messaging. And my setting config for the channel layer is:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

**Update**

I am using django-channels-presence to figure out who the users are connected in the same group(room). Is there a way to send a specific message to each user in the same connected group?

Suggestion on better code implementation that can be scalable is highly appreciated.

Comment: You defined socket.send twice... is that necessary?

Comment: Those two events are based on user event selection. When the user clicks the button to select the seat select event will be sent and when the user deselects the selected seat deselect event will be fired.